# What is the meaning of "lecture-agent" here? Do author wants to say that the failure of her lecture is because of funds?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "lecture-agent" here? Do author wants to say that the failure of her lecture is because of funds?

> To give greater authenticity to the interview, at her suggestion the
>   following open letter was written to which she placed her signature:
>   128, West Forty-third Street, New York City, November 16, 1889. TO THE
>   PUBLIC. The foregoing interview having been read over to me I find
>   nothing contained therein that is not a correct record of my words and
>   truthful expression of my sentiments. I have not given a detailed
>   account of the ways and means which were devised to bring me under
>   subjection, and so extract from me a declaration that the spiritual
>   phenomena as exemplified through my organism were a fraud. But I shall
>   fully atone for this incompleteness when I get upon the platform. The
>   exactness of this interview was testified to by the names of a number
>   of witnesses, including J. L. O'Sullivan, who was U.S. Minister to
>   Portugal for twenty-five years. He said, "If ever I heard a woman
>   speak truth, it was then." **So it may have been, but the failure of her
>   lecture-agent to keep her in funds seems to have been the determining
>   factor.**

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Her agent would have been the person who found venues for her lectures and organised the business arrangements.